# How to use Router inside a shell script?

Tags: shell, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a script in `app/vendors/shells` which is executed periodically via cron. In that script I import the `Router`:

```
class AutosuggestFileShell extends Shell {
    var $uses = array('User','Country','City','Speciality','Alias');

    function main() {
        App::import('Core', 'Router');
        //...
```

But the script is not using the routes I have defined in `routes.php`. For example, I have defined:

```
Router::connect('/plastic-surgeon/*', array(
    'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'
));
```

But in the script the line:

```
'path' => Router::url(array(
    'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile', $user['User']['slug']
))
```

is not generating the URL `plastic-surgeon/slug` - instead it generates the URL `users/profile/slug`.

`Router::url()` works fine in different points of the website, for example inside a view to generate a sitemap. Therefore I guess I need to import something from the shell script or maybe it is not possible to load the data contained in `routes.php` from the shell script?

(I'm using CakePHP 1.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you want to import the routes try

```
config('routes');
```

Comment: This didnt work for me. I put it inline before any execution.